# Python: Can't get module sklearn to work... OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, scikit-learn, oserror

I'm using Visual studio and am trying to learn how to use scikit-learn/sklearn. I installed it and all the other packages using 'pip' without any problems.

I literally am only trying to import it. No other code yet.

Whenever I try to import it though, I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/samir/Code/Machine Learning A-Z/Machine Learning A-Z (Codes and Datasets)/Part 1 - Data Preprocessing/Section 2 Part 1 - Data Preprocessing/Python/data_preprocessing_Samir.py", line 20, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Users\samir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\samir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "C:\Users\samir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse
  File "C:\Users\samir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\samir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Answer (score 0):

You need openslide windows libraries. Use either of the links below to obtain the binary.

32-bit: https://github.com/openslide/openslide-winbuild/releases/download/v20171122/openslide-win32-20171122.zip

64-bit: https://github.com/openslide/openslide-winbuild/releases/download/v20171122/openslide-win64-20171122.zip

After installation, open directory to which you installed to, and find the "bin" folder and add it to your windows path.

To add the path to "bin" folder to the Path variable, start the Run box and enter "sysdm.cpl"

[image]

This should open up the System Properties window. Go to the "Advanced" tab and click the "Environment Variables" button:

[image]

In the "System variable" window, find the "Path" variable and click Edit:

enter image description here

Position your cursor at the end of the Variable value line and add the path to the python.exe file, preceeded with the semicolon character (;). In our example, we have added the following value: ;C:\Python34. (But for you, add the openslide "bin" folder instead)

[image]

Close all windows. Now you can run sklearn.